# Computing a subgroup of the Galois group of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt3,\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[4]2,i)$

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm trying to compute the subgroup $H$ of the Galois group of $K = \Bbb Q(\sqrt3,\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[4]2,i)$ corresponding to the subfield $E = \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[4]2)$.

So far I've computed $[K:\Bbb Q] = 48$ and $[E:\Bbb Q] = 12$, and I know that by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, $|H| = 4$. I know that $Gal(E|\Bbb Q) = \{id,\sigma\}$, where $\sigma$ sends $\sqrt[4]2$ to its opposite. But there has to be another $\tau\in H$ with $|\tau| = 2$, since $|\sigma| = 2$, and we would perhaps get $H = \langle \sigma,\tau\rangle$.

I don't have the Galois group of $K$. Should I compute that first and then go for the subgroup by hand, or is there something else that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The correspondence between subgroups and subfields is related to fields fixed by the subgroup. Do you want the subgroup whose fixed field is $E$?

Comment: To answer Paramanand, that's what I'm looking for. To answer KCd, I will edit it with the corresponding order fixed. I edited it, but didn't change the part below, which shows that $|H| = 4$. My apologies to both of you for making the question ambiguous or wrong from the start.

Comment: The extension $E/\mathbf Q$ is *not* Galois. It is irrelevant what the $\mathbf Q$- automorphisms of $E$ are. You want the $E$-automorphisms of $K$. The Galois correspondence turns things upside down (inclusion reversing) by focusing on what elements of the full Galois group *fix* everything in the intermediate field $E$.

Comment: I was trying to find two $\Bbb Q$.automorphisms of $K$ and try to compute them somehow to fix $\sqrt[3]2$ and $\sqrt[4]2$. I've done a similar exercise but the other way around, and with a Galois group of less degree, but this is quite harder for me. Any tips on how to continue?

Comment: Wait, so we only have to consider $\sigma$ the function that sends $\sqrt3$ to $-\sqrt3$ and fixes the rest of 'generators' and $\tau$ the function that sends $i$ to $-i$ and fixes the rest of the 'generators' and $\langle\sigma,\tau\rangle = H$? Or am I doing something wrong?